# Copying parent node value to child nodes

Tags: xslt

I want to copy the value of parentnode element into child node, as shown below. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?
Thank you!

Here is the xml file.

```
<mainpart id="295928" num="1-MS15" quantity="1">
    <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
    <proxy id="1E2B4D" ACADID="1E2B4E" basepart="58A67">
        <singlepart id="24558D" num="1-m81" ncFile="1-m81.nc1" quantity="1">
            <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
            <part id="58A67" name="C4X6.25" class="Beam" ACADID="59582" dstvName="C4X6.25">
                <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                <role key="Frame" name="FRAME"/>
                <length>1727.194</length>
                <paintArea>618840.532</paintArea>
                <numHoles>8</numHoles>
                <ObjectTopLevel>0.739</ObjectTopLevel>
                <ObjectBottomLevel>-101.741</ObjectBottomLevel>
                <material key="ASTM-A36" name="A36"/>
                <coating key="G" name="G"/>
                <commodity>FRAME</commodity>
                <weight>16064.68</weight>
                <exactWeight>15945.55</exactWeight>
                <weightPerMeter>9301.02</weightPerMeter>
                <density>7850.00</density>
                <section key="AISC 14.1 C Channel#@§@#ChannelsC4X6.25" name="C4X6.25"/>
                <sysLength>1727.194</sysLength>
                <sawLength>1727.194</sawLength>
                <angleX1>0.0000</angleX1>
                <angleY1>0.0000</angleY1>
                <angleX2>0.0000</angleX2>
                <angleY2>0.0000</angleY2>
                <SawCutInfo>0</SawCutInfo>
                <ElementID>7400</ElementID>
            </part>
        </singlepart>
        <singlepart id="295ADA" num="1-p3" quantity="4">
            <explicitQuantity>4</explicitQuantity>
            <part id="295C18" name="PL 1/4&quot;x1 3/8&quot;" class="Plate" ACADID="295C14" dstvName="PL 1/4&quot;">
                <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                <role key="Plate" name="PLATE"/>
                <length>85.725</length>
                <paintArea>7215.343</paintArea>
                <ObjectTopLevel>-7.199</ObjectTopLevel>
                <ObjectBottomLevel>-93.396</ObjectBottomLevel>
                <material key="ASTM-A36" name="A36"/>
                <coating key="G" name="G"/>
                <weight>143.81</weight>
                <exactWeight>143.81</exactWeight>
                <density>7850.00</density>
                <thickness>6.350</thickness>
                <width>35.535</width>
                <area1>2884.914</area1>
                <area2>2884.914</area2>
                <contourLength>227.640</contourLength>
                <ElementID>52306</ElementID>
                <ElementID>52304</ElementID>
                <ElementID>52303</ElementID>
                <ElementID>52305</ElementID>
            </part>
        </singlepart>
    </proxy>
</mainpart>
```

Here is my xsl, I know it is wrong, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mainpart" >
        <xsl:variable name="mainpartmark" select="@name" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="part">     
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <UserAttribute10>"$mainpartmark"</UserAttribute10>  
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the result I wanted, I want to add the node UserAttr10 on each end of Part node with value of num from mainpart node.

```
<mainpart id="295928" num="1-MS15" quantity="1">
    <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
    <proxy id="1E2B4D" ACADID="1E2B4E" basepart="58A67">
        <singlepart id="24558D" num="1-m81" ncFile="1-m81.nc1" quantity="1">
            <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
            <part id="58A67" name="C4X6.25" class="Beam" ACADID="59582" dstvName="C4X6.25">
                <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                <role key="Frame" name="FRAME"/>
                <length>1727.194</length>
                <paintArea>618840.532</paintArea>
                <numHoles>8</numHoles>
                <ObjectTopLevel>0.739</ObjectTopLevel>
                <ObjectBottomLevel>-101.741</ObjectBottomLevel>
                <material key="ASTM-A36" name="A36"/>
                <coating key="G" name="G"/>
                <commodity>FRAME</commodity>
                <weight>16064.68</weight>
                <exactWeight>15945.55</exactWeight>
                <weightPerMeter>9301.02</weightPerMeter>
                <density>7850.00</density>
                <section key="AISC 14.1 C Channel#@§@#ChannelsC4X6.25" name="C4X6.25"/>
                <sysLength>1727.194</sysLength>
                <sawLength>1727.194</sawLength>
                <angleX1>0.0000</angleX1>
                <angleY1>0.0000</angleY1>
                <angleX2>0.0000</angleX2>
                <angleY2>0.0000</angleY2>
                <SawCutInfo>0</SawCutInfo>
                <ElementID>7400</ElementID>
                <UserAttr10>1-MS15</UserAttr10> <!--Add this line-->
            </part>
        </singlepart>
        <singlepart id="295ADA" num="1-p3" quantity="4">
            <explicitQuantity>4</explicitQuantity>
            <part id="295C18" name="PL 1/4&quot;x1 3/8&quot;" class="Plate" ACADID="295C14" dstvName="PL 1/4&quot;">
                <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                <role key="Plate" name="PLATE"/>
                <length>85.725</length>
                <paintArea>7215.343</paintArea>
                <ObjectTopLevel>-7.199</ObjectTopLevel>
                <ObjectBottomLevel>-93.396</ObjectBottomLevel>
                <material key="ASTM-A36" name="A36"/>
                <coating key="G" name="G"/>
                <weight>143.81</weight>
                <exactWeight>143.81</exactWeight>
                <density>7850.00</density>
                <thickness>6.350</thickness>
                <width>35.535</width>
                <area1>2884.914</area1>
                <area2>2884.914</area2>
                <contourLength>227.640</contourLength>
                <ElementID>52306</ElementID>
                <ElementID>52304</ElementID>
                <ElementID>52303</ElementID>
                <ElementID>52305</ElementID>
                <UserAttr10>1-MS15</UserAttr10> <!--Add this line-->
            </part>
        </singlepart>
    </proxy>
</mainpart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is only one `mainpart` node (the root element), simply declare your variable as a global variable (a child of `xsl:stylesheet`)

```
<xsl:variable name="mainpartmark" select="/mainpart/@num" />
```

(You wouldn't need the template matching `mainpart` in this case).

Then, to use it, just do this...

```
<UserAttribute10>
   <xsl:value-of select="/mainpart/@num" />
</UserAttribute10>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="mainpartmark" select="/mainpart/@num" />

    <xsl:template match="part">     
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <UserAttribute10>
                <xsl:value-of select="$mainpartmark" />
            </UserAttribute10>  
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, you could also do it without the variable at all, and just do `<xsl:value-of select="/mainpart/@num" />` instead.

And, if there were multiple `mainpart` nodes (under a single root element), you could also do `<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::mainpart/@num" />`

Comment: Thanks, Tim!. As always you are a big help.